# Trigger increment for PgAdmin

Tags: c, postgresql, triggers, increment

So I need to define some triggers for my database. So far, I only got one.
I'll explain first, then i'll post the code aswell.

So I have table "Persons" and I set a trigger whenever I insert something in Persons, IdPerson (pk) will increment eachtime. It goes like this

```
create sequence seqpersoane START WITH 9913 INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 9912 
MAXVALUE 9999 NO CYCLE;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_persoane()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $trg_persoane$
BEGIN
NEW.idpersoana = NEXTVAL('seqpersoane') ;
RETURN NEW ;
END ;
$trg_persoane$ LANGUAGE plpgsql ;

CREATE TRIGGER trg_persoane
BEFORE INSERT ON persoane
for each row execute procedure trg_persoane();

INSERT INTO persoane VALUES (1221, 'Hanu Ana-Maria', '06929395832', 
'romana', 'hanu@gmail.com', '1995-05-28');
```

Last insert is to test, and is working. I got IdPerson 9913.

Then, I have a table "Students" with pk IDSTUDENT (idstudent = idperson from table PERSONS, because, you know, students are also persons and have  the same ID)

Now, i do not know the code, that, whenever I INSERT a PERSON (name, telephone, email, and other general details) I have to INSERT ALSO the STUDENT with the same incremented ID as in PERSONS.

So i insert person with idperson 9914. Next, I insert student, with the same code for increment as i used in person (increment by one starts with 9914). So both have the same Incremented ID Cuz both started with the same START WITH NUMBER.

But then, lets say I miss spell the name of a person i wanna insert, and I get an IDPERSON 9915. I DELETE THAT PERSON, and INSERT AGAIN with another ID PERSON 9916. The problem is the IDSTUDENT will remain 9915 and it violates the FK.

Helperino. Sorry for the long post. I.ll give you a potato at the end.

EDIT:

if i try this on table STUDENT and also on table EMPLOYEE

```
create sequence seqStudent START WITH 9913 INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 9912 
MAXVALUE 9999 NO CYCLE; 
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_student()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $trg_student$
BEGIN 
NEW.idstudent = CURRVAL('seqpersoane') ;
RETURN NEW ; 
END ; 
$trg_student$ LANGUAGE plpgsql ; 


CREATE TRIGGER trg_student 
BEFORE INSERT ON student 
for each row execute procedure trg_student();
```

Comment: You shouldn't use a separate sequence for a foreign key. If you do the insert in one transaction (or rather: in the same *session*), you can use `SELECT currval('seqpersoane')` to find out, which was the last generated sequence value (by the `SELECT nextval('seqpersoane')` call). Another option (or, if you insert these entities in a different session), you can use the `INSERT INTO persoane VALUES (...) RETURNING idperson` syntax to get the generated ID for the person. You can use that later to insert relevant records for other tables.

Comment: Hmm.. logic it would be whenI choose to delete a miss spelled insert of a person, the next idperson would be simmilar with the one deleted. In that case both sequences from student and person would have a simmilar id. Out of curiousity, im kinda newbie with this. If you can post how my code should look like for table STUDENT, i would appreciate it

Comment: [this](http://rextester.com/YJG48931) is f.ex. a usual setup.

Comment: The point is.. I use another Table called EMPLOYEE that has the same concept as STUDENT.. IDEmployee = idperson.. and if i insert one person, then I add student they will both have the same ID. But when i insert another person, that person will have IDPERSON +2 while IdEmployee only +1. So another violation cuz IdEmployee != idperson..

Comment: @pozs watch the edit.